# Record enter button in qtp

Tags: qtp

How to record ENTER button that we use through the keyboard in QTP for applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to **replay** an <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, in most cases when QTP does not **record** an action it's much better to add the step manually than trying to force QTP to record it.

If the test object in question supports `Type` you can use that:

```
Window("Calc").Type micReturn
```

Otherwise you can use the `DeviceReplay` object as described in [this article](http://www.advancedqtp.com/knowledge-base/articles/qtp-tricks4/the-undocumented-devicereplay/)

```
Set dr = CreateObject("Mercury.DeviceReplay")
dr.PressKey 28 ' 28 = Return (Enter)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option to replay an Enter button press would be to simply use the SendKeys Method of the Windows Script Host object. The code would look something like this:

```
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WShell.script")
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Set WshShell = Nothing
```